# Flocking/ Boids Algorithm : Field Of view specified by angle in 3D

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, simulation, angle

I am trying to make boids algorithm in Unity 3D.

I got into one problem: How to implement field of view in specific angle?

360 degrees is easy - U check only distance between two boids. But I dont want boids able to look behind themself. I also want to be able to change angle of view in Inspector, so it must be based on calculations.

I would be gratefull for any ideas:(

[image]
[image]

I already tried with mesh collider which is cone but it didnt go well. - not working for 180 and higher. So I am looking best way to calculate this.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that the boid is at point `p = (p.x, p.y, p.z)` heading toward some point `h = (h.x, h.y, h.z)`, and we want to know whether an object at point `q = (q.x, q.y, q.z)` is in the boid's field of vision.

The Law of Cosines gives us a formula for the cosine of the angle `φ` between the boid's heading and the boid's path to the object:

```
          (h−p) · (q−p)
cos(φ) = ---------------
         ||h−p|| ||q−p||

       = (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2 + dz1*dz2) /
         (sqrt(dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1 + dz1*dz1) * sqrt(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2 + dz2*dz2))
```

where

```
dx1 = h.x - p.x
dy1 = h.y - p.y
dz1 = h.z - p.z
dx2 = q.x - p.x
dy2 = q.y - p.y
dz2 = q.z - p.z
```

Given some angle `ρ` (in whatever units your cosine function accepts, usually radians) past which the boid cannot see (putting the field of vision at `2ρ`), we have

```
φ > ρ  if and only if  cos(φ) < cos(ρ),
```

so we can precompute `cos(ρ)` and then use the above formula for repeated tests.

To avoid division by zero and other numerical problems, you might want to check whether the denominator of the division is very small and if so declare that the boid can feel whatever the object is even outside its field of vision.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for answer. However I dont really understand how did you get that formula? I believed law of cosinus standed for another equation

Comment: I divided through by the norms: http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2006/07/dot-product-and-cosine.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I have been looking everywhere, and this is by far the best answer. I’m trying to accomplish the same thing, but I’m programming in p5.js.  I don’t want to duplicate this question, but I have some follow-up questions to this answer that I can’t cover in a comment.  I posted my implementation (currently not working) of your answer here:

https://gist.github.com/Zearin/a632965873644db1538fbd6ffb65ae63

Could you point out where I’m going wrong?

Comment: @Zearin the variable that you named `relTheta` is being set to cos theta, so the `p.cos(relTheta)` below should be just `relTheta` (which should probably be named `cosRelTheta` to avoid confusion). Also, `p5.Vector.sub(this.velocity, this.position)` looks suspicious if you mean velocity in the traditional sense. `h` in this answer is a destination point, and `h-p` should have the same direction as the boid's velocity if it's headed there.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: But *should* I be calling the `cos()` function on `relTheta`?  I am trying to determine if I accurately translated your answer into code.  

As for `this.velocity`, it actually does describe the boid’s destination. (This code began with my copying a simple example, then modifying it bit by bit as I learn the p5.js library. The variable was originally named `velocity`, and I kept it for referring back to the original.)

Comment: (I just updated my gist with a `relCosTheta` variable as well, in addition to the original `relTheta` variable.)

Comment: @Zearin no, you shouldn't be calling cos on the quotient. The right definition is `const cosRelTheta = numerator / denominator`.